# How to disable UIButton Tint Color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I know my case may be rare but how do you disable the UIButton tint colour in this case?

I have a customised UIButton which has attributedTitle to help display the button pattern in different colour and alpha.

[image]

In my customised button .m file I have set something like this

```
[self setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor grayColor]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

which will make the background colour to gray when the button is selected

However the real result looks like this:

[image]

Some how the text colour gets turned into white which I think is because of the tint effect on UIButtons.

Is that possible for me to have the background as grey while the text still remain the colour as set in the attributed title on selected state of the button?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of an attributed title, you should set the text color for both the normal and selected states.

Comment: setbackground color for the button.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
yourbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

                        (or)
```

If u placed button in storyboard....Choose button type as custom instead of system.

Comment: Hmmm, Xcode 10, iOS 12.4 ... Doesn't work for me.  My button is custom, placed and configured manually in a xib file.

Answer (score 15):

You can override `setImage:forState:` in `UIButton` subclass and change rendering mode to `.alwaysOriginal`.

```
override func setImage(_ image: UIImage?, for state: UIControlState) {
    let newImage = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    super.setImage(newImage, for: state)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple, just head to the image in your assets, and set its **rendering** **mode** to **"Original Image"**, check image below:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Follow this steps to get result:

- First set `UITabBar` background color to clear
- Now put this line in viewDidLoad method of the first page:

  `[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:SETYOURCOLOR];`

Hope it will help you.